# Ninject.Web.Common No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject.web

I used Nuget to install the Ninject.Web.Common reference. I use it with ASP.net Web API (APIController) with no problem, but I hit problem when using the ASP.net MVC 4(Controller).

The error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CarsApp.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(CarsApp.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace CarsApp.Web.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    //using App.WebUI.Infrastructure;
    using App.Domain.Abstract;
    using App.Domain.Concreate;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using App.Web.Infrastructure;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            // Install our Ninject-based IDependencyResolver into the Web API config
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IMembershipRepository>().To<EFMembershipRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IBranchRepository>().To<EFBranchRepository>();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: At the right side of your screen you'll see at least 7 questions with the same error. Can you tell us what suggestions you have attempted and what the results were?

Answer (score 1):

I am using MVC5 and using Install-Package Ninject.MVC5 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try with Install-Package Ninject.MVC3

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your Web.config you have two lines for MVC versioning, I had something like:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

If you do then replace them with one line like, to redirect to highest version that you are using in my case it's `4.0.0.1`:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This did it for me.